# How do I figure out which groups in a Pandas Dataframe have a sequence of events in a specific order?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe regarding analytics tracking of user behaviour.
It has a structure like this:

[image]

I want to count the number of sessions in which eventA happens and, in a later timestamp, eventB happens within the same session (For example, there's only one session, id 101, in the sample picture where there's eventA first and eventB later)

I can't for the life of me figure out the best way to do it.

I've tried two approaches, both of them resulting in being way too convoluted:

Approach 1)

- I've filtered by event typeB, grouped by session, extracted the max timestamp
- Then I've filtered by event typeA, grouped by session, extracted the min timestamp
- Merged the two sets of data, to compare when the min timestamp for eventA is non-null and lesser than timestamp for eventB

It's too much code and difficult to check for validity

Approach 2)
I was suggested by my manager to:

- sort by session and timestamp (as in the example)
- use the where clause to add a column "eventB_timestamp" valued only for rows with eventB
- use a backward-fill to propagate the value
- confront the event_timestamp on rows with eventA with the "eventB_timestamp" value

But it's also convoluted, and it risks of reading data from the wrong sessions.

I'm trying to look up online a more natural way to solve the issue, but I can't find anything

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
import numpy as np

types = ['typeA', 'typeB']
for type_ in types:
    df[f'event_{type_}_timestamp'] = np.where(df['event_name'] == f'interesting_event_{type_}', 
                                              df['event_timestamp'], 
                                              np.NaN)

df_events = df.groupby('user_session_id').agg({'event_typeA_timestamp': 'min', 
                                               'event_typeB_timestamp': 'max'}) 

print((df_events['event_typeA_timestamp'] < df_events['event_typeB_timestamp']).sum())
```

It's similar to your first approach, but without a merge.
Hope it's not too convoluted.

Comment: This is VERY cool. So simple, yet it didn't cross my mind. I'm kind of a newbie when it comes to data manipulation (I only recently made the switch from sw development to data science). Thank you!